# Using subdomains, separate databases, and virtual hosts to scale SAAS

Tags: lamp, subdomain, crm, saas

I am building office management software on a LAMP server on a SAAS model. My clients typically have 5-10 thousand customers they are tracking with all of their contact, invoicing, appointment information. I want to keep each clients information in a separate Database. This I believe will in the long run improve performance, ensure better separation of data, and be cleaner.

So what I want to have happen is for company1.mysite.com and company2.mysite.com to both point to the same site, but pass on their subdomain as a parameter to php.

How do I use apache and vhosts to pass on the subdomain as a parameter to php while still using the same application for all subdomains.

Comment: Database architecture is probably way off topic here, IMHO.

Comment: Well, more so I'm interested in structuring it from the Apache perspective with subdomains. Like company1.mysite.com connects to company1 database while company2.mysite.com connects to company2 database. That's what I think I want, but am open to suggestions if there is a better way.

Comment: Apache knows nothing about the database your application uses. You'll need to handle that in php.

Comment: I just edited the question, I didn't explain what I wanted very well

Answer (score 2):

This probably belongs on Stack Overflow, but...

In your PHP code, you check the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to determine the hostname which was used.

In your Apache `<VirtualHost>` use a [wildcard `ServerAlias`](https://serverfault.com/q/139628/126632) to serve all possible subdomains of the domain name from the same virtual host.

Comment: Something about this seems a bit insecure.. or at least security thru obscurity..